# Why is the radical of 午 listed as ⼗ and not ⼲?

Tags: radicals

I am having a lot of trouble determining the radicals and other components of various kanji.  I figure that there's some historical reason, but does anyone know exactly why the radical of 午 is ⼗?

Comment: Radicals are arbitrary assignments of characters to dictionary headings to make character lookup somewhat more organised. If you’re looking at character components which contribute some sort of functionality to characters, ask about “character components”.

Comment: The (venerated / old school) "Nelson Japanese-English Character Dictionary" actually has 午 indexed under the ノ radical  (ノ冠). In Nelson, top / left trumps other radicals. I think kanwa-jiten do as well. These new electronic kanji dictionaries use different rules for radicals than the written kanji dictionaries that have been used for decades, is my sense.

Comment: @user312440 : Make that _”rules for radicals [in] the written dictionaries that have been used for **centuries**”_.  See, for example, the Kangxi dictionary entry [here](http://www.kangxizidian.com/kangxi/0156.gif). The [Kangxi dictionary](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kangxi_Dictionary) is a Chinese dictionary published in 1716, using [a radical system established in 1615](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zihui).

Comment: Anyway, I hope these comments have indicated that you're actually asking the wrong question. Specifically for 午, it is not comprised of any other component; it is a picture of a *pestle*, now written using the derivative 杵. The meaning *noon* is a phonetic loan.